FormBuilder "is one of" list of emails
I'm working on a form to make updating participant statuses easier for my staff.
We've got CSVs with a list of emails in them for everyone that attended an event. In SearchKit, I can search for Participants, that attended Event ID X, that have Email "is one of" and copy and paste the full list of 400 some-odd emails into the box, and it automatically does what I want: finds all the participants for that event with these email addresses so I can easily modify this set all at once.
When I try to replicate that in FormBuilder so that end users can just copy/paste their list of emails, any time I try to use Email with the "is one of" operator, it just doesn't return any results. Maybe I'm doing something wrong with the formatting? But I tried: comma delineated (which works in SearchKit), space delineated, in parentheses, in quotes, all the standard formatting that I can think of, and none of them return any results.
It also throws some Angular errors:
    TypeError: apiResults is undefined
    Angular 2
        initializeDisplay
        runSearch
    Lodash 2
        qt
        Re
    Angular 6
        runSearch
        k
        $digest
        evalAsync
        completeTask
        d
 Possibly unhandled rejection: {} angular.js:15697:15
    Angular 7
        e
        get
        g
        $digest
        evalAsync
        completeTask
        dTypeError: apiResults is undefined
    Angular 2
        initializeDisplay
        runSearch
    Lodash 2
        qt
        Re
    Angular 6
        runSearch
        k
        $digest
        evalAsync
        completeTask
        d
 Possibly unhandled rejection: {} angular.js:15697:15
    Angular 7
        e
        get
        g
        $digest
        evalAsync
        completeTask
        d

Suggestions?

Not really a direct answer to your question, but another way to update the status of these participants would be as a 'participant import' (which doesn't have to be new participants, it can also update specific values of existing participants). You'd have to add a column to your spreadsheet with the id of the event and maybe another one with the updated status value, but the email value should work to identify the participant.
